# AsyncStorage.getItem in react native not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm setting data on the server with `AsyncStorage.setItem` and trying to access that value in another screen using `AsyncStorage.getItem`. 
1. I can't set the `token` within `AsyncStorage`.
2. How do I set multiple values within asyncstorage, say I want `user_id` from server response to be set along with this `token`?

```
onPressRegister(){

            fetch('http://192.168.1.7:3000/users/registration',{
                method:'POST',
                headers:{
                    'Accept': 'applictaion/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',

                },
                body:JSON.stringify({
           contact:this.state.contact,
                     password:this.state.password,
                })
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) =>
            {
                 this.setState({
                     signup: responseData
                 });
                 setTimeout(() => {
                    Actions.firstScreen();
                }, 2300);

        AsyncStorage.setItem('token' ,this.state.signup.token);
            });

    }
```

And I'm fetching like this

```
  componentDidMount(){
    AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then((userid) =>{
    this.setState({'userid': userid});
    console.log(userid);
    });
}
```

But I can't see the result within `console` nothing is getting. Is there any mistake in `AsyncStorage.setItem` ?Also, the server response looks like this

```
{ error: 0,
  data: 'User registered Successfully',
  userData:
   { pwd: 'vgh',
     phone_no: '5',
     user_name: '',
     status: 1,
     date: 2018-10-23T09:23:53.671Z },
  user_id: [  { user_id: 5 } ],
  token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9' }
```

Also I want `user_id` to be set within `AsyncStorage`. How to do this?

Comment: why wouldn't you `AsyncStorage.setItem('token', responseData.token);`

Comment: I can't find this link

Comment: I think it meant https://github.com/jasonmerino/react-native-simple-store

Comment: @JaromandaX actually I'm setting the response as a state variable so I can use it then ryt?

Comment: well, yes, I'm just saying `responseData.token` is shorter and more obvious than `this.state.signup.token` - it makes no difference to the result - unless of course `this.setState` happens to be **asynchronous** (which I thought was the case)

Comment: I tried that too..but can't find any result.

Comment: probably more asynchrony you aren't taking into account - don't know

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried `react-native-simple-store`.  I tried like this `store.save('userid').then((token) =>{
       this.setState({'userid':token })
       console.log(token);
      });` but nothing is geting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use `async` and `await` for accessing the value from AsyncStorage.

```
async componentDidMount(){
    let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    console.log(token);
}
```

Comment: first u have to try static data store ex : AsyncStorage. setItem('token','test'); than try to get

Comment: So where ever I use `getItem` should I use `setItem` before that?Even though I'm setting `token` in a different page? please help.I've used `AsyncStorage` in earlier project also that time it was easy.The only difference is I was using `react-navigation` for navigation but in this pjct I'm using `react-native-router-flux` .

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue come from the async property of setState.

If your responseData is an object (test it with console.log(typeof responseData), 
Try it :

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('token' , responseData.token);
```

Indeed, the setState method take a time to be effective. React native set the state when it is the best moment, and not when you write it in your code (async function). It is not like a variable set..

Another thing to know is when you call getItem. If you call it just after setItem (or even after navigating to another screen), it could not be already set (same async Reason). Then you can do like this to be sure your item has been set :

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('token' , responseData.token, () => { ...the next instructions (like navigation function) });
```

It is a callback called at the end of the setItem method

Comment: I've tried like this  `AsyncStorage.setItem('token' , responseData.token, () => { Actions.firstScreen(); })` .But no result